Terraform AzureRM - route table BGP propagation failing
I'm trying to create a route table with bgp_route_propagation_enabled set as false. When I run my CI/CD pipeline it fails at the plan stage with the following error:
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on modules/vnet/module.tf line 39, in resource "azurerm_route_table" "rt":
│   39:   bgp_route_propagation_enabled = false
│ 
│ An argument named "bgp_route_propagation_enabled" is not expected here.

The resource block I'm using is:
resource "azurerm_route_table" "rt" {
  name                          = "test-resource"
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  bgp_route_propagation_enabled = false

    dynamic "route" {
    for_each = var.route-internet
    content {
      name                   = route.value["name"]
      address_prefix         = route.value["address_prefix"]
      next_hop_type          = route.value["next_hop"]
      next_hop_in_ip_address = route.value["ip"]
    } 
  }
}

I'm using Terraform version 1.8.0 and AzureRM version 3.103.1
I've tried the above code block and expecting BGP route propagation to be set to false.

try updating your provider version to the latest and try again @Matty

with the latest version its working seamlessly image  even though the version its supporting is from 3.67 https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/releases?q=bgp_route_propagation_enabled&expanded=true

@VinayB perfect thanks for this! Upgraded to provider version 4.5.0 and it's all working, looks like that argument isn't supported in version 3.103.1.


Route table BGP propagation failing due to version issue

As per the github release the property mentioned is supported from the 3.67 in route_table configuration
Even through you provided a version 3.103.1 there might be some descrepences in state file version and endup failing as you mentioned.
It's always best practice uses the latest version of provider which helps in achieving the best possible security and features.
demo configuration:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=4.9.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
} 
.
.
resource "azurerm_route_table" "rt" {
  name                = "test-route-table"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  bgp_route_propagation_enabled = false

 
  dynamic "route" {
    for_each = var.route_internet
    content {
      name           = route.value["name"]
      address_prefix = route.value["address_prefix"]
      next_hop_type  = route.value["next_hop"]
      next_hop_in_ip_address = route.value["next_hop"] != "Internet" ? route.value["ip"] : null
    }
  }
}

Deployment:

